# Find average for records with aggregated count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the average in a table that includes a count in each record.

I need to find the average as though there were individual records for each count listed in the record.

For example:

```html
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
| Color | Value_to_Average | Number_of_Records |
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
| Red   |                3 |                 2 |
| Red   |                2 |                 3 |
| Green |                5 |                 2 |
| Blue  |                1 |                 2 |
+-------+------------------+-------------------+
```

When I average the values individually, the result is 2.66667.  How can I get this same result from the records with the counts?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d44f2/1/0)

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is it as simple as Value_To_Average / Number_Of_Records???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a weighted average:

```
select sum(Value_to_Average * Number_of_Records) / sum(Number_of_Records)
from Color_Avg t;
```

Comment: Thank you!  So simple now that I see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select (sum(value_to_average)*sum(number_of_records))/cast(sum(number_of_records) as double)  
from table
```